# How to access webservicecontext programatically in apache cxf?

Tags: cxf

Is there a way to access webservicecontext in the following format

SomeUtil.getWebserviceContext() instead of

@Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just do:

new org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl()

and use that.   That's the object that is injected and it just wraps a thread local.

Answer (score -1):

Migrating from old CXF 2.2 to 2.7.0, I was unable to access to the WebServiceContext, this line works fine:

```
new org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl()
```